# Vue.js - серверная валидация, обработка ошибок, вывод ошибок

Tags: javascript, form, vue.js, frontend, валидация

Хочу выводить сообщение об ошибке в span'e под текстовым input'ом моей формы. Я использую только серверную валидацию.

Также, хочу оптимизировать и сократить код, используя массивы и циклы.

```
<template>
<div id='wrapper'>
<form class='form' v-on:submit.prevent="onSubmit">
  <h1>Contact Us</h1>
  <div class='field'>
    <input class='text-input' v-model="formData.name" id='name' name='name' type='text' placeholder="Name">
    <span v-if="showNameMsg" class="danger">{{nameErrorMsg}}</span>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <input class="text-input" v-model="formData.email" id='email' name='email' type='text' placeholder="Email">
    <span v-if="showEmailMsg" class="danger">{{emailErrorMsg}}</span>
  </div>
  <div class='field'>
    <textarea class='textarea' v-model="formData.text" cols='10' id='message' name='message' rows='1' placeholder="Message"></textarea>
    <span v-if="showTextMsg" class="danger">{{textErrorMsg}}</span>
  </div>
  <div class='field'>
    <input class='button' type='submit' value='Submit' >
  </div>
</form>
```

```
import {Post} from '../services/postService.js'

export default {

data() {
  return {
    formData: {
      email: "",
      name: "",
      text: "",
    },

    showEmailMsg: false,
    showNameMsg: false,
    showTextMsg: false,

    emailErrorMsg: '',
    nameErrorMsg: '',
    textErrorMsg: ''
  }


},

methods: {
  async onSubmit() {
    if (this.formData.email.indexOf("@.") === -1) {
      this.showEmailMsg = true;
    }
    else this.showEmailMsg = false;

    if (this.formData.name === "") {
      this.showNameMsg = true;
    }
    else this.showNameMsg = false;

    if (this.formData.text === "") {
      this.showTextMsg = true;
    }
    else this.showTextMsg = false;

      try {
        await Post(this.formData)
      } catch (e) {
        this.emailErrorMsg = e.response.data.email[0];
        this.textErrorMsg = e.response.data.text[0];
        this.nameErrorMsg = e.response.data.name[0];
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: На русском stackoverflow принято задавать вопросы на русском языке.

Comment: да, уже понял это, внесены правки. кто может  помочь?

Answer (score 0):

```
<template>
<div id='wrapper'>
<form class='form' v-on:submit.prevent="onSubmit">
  <h1>Contact Us</h1>
  <div class='field'>
    <input class='text-input' v-model="formData.name" id='name' type='text' placeholder="Name">
    <span class="danger">{{errArray['name']?errArray['name'].toString():''}}</span>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <input class="text-input" v-model="formData.email" id='email' type='text' placeholder="Email">
    <span class="danger">{{errArray['email']?errArray['email'].toString():''}}</span>
  </div>
  <div class='field'>
    <textarea class='textarea' v-model="formData.text" cols='10' id='text' rows='1' placeholder="Message"></textarea>
    <span class="danger">{{errArray['text']?errArray['text'].toString():''}}</span>
  </div>
  <div class='field'>
    <input class='button' type='submit' value='Submit' >
  </div>
  <span id='err' class="danger"></span>
</form>
```

```
import {Post} from '../services/postService.js'

export default {

data() {
  return {
    formData: {
      email: "",
      name: "",
      text: "",
    },
    errArray: [],
  }
},

methods: {
  async onSubmit() {
    try {
      await Post(this.formData)
    } catch (e) {
      this.errArray = e.response.data;
    }
  }
}
```

}